# How to implement search functionality when there is 3 texboxes and one search button in mvc 4

Tags: entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[upload] (
    [docid]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [clientid]     INT            NULL,
    [clientname]   NVARCHAR (15)  NULL,
    [employeeid]   INT            NULL,
    [empcitizenid] INT            NULL,
    [employeename] NVARCHAR (15)  NULL,
    [nationality]  NVARCHAR (20)  NULL,
    [filepath]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [filename]     NVARCHAR (100) NULL)
```

In my view there are 3 textboxes which accept clientd,employeeid,empcitizenid and one search button. When the textbox data matches with database below i want to bind data to web grid.
Now for search there are 6 scenarios. 
1. If all three textboxes contain valid data then success
2.if one of them contain valid data, then remaining empty then also success
3.all all contains invalid data then invalid.
4. if any of the two textboxes contain valid data then success like this there are many scenarios. What is the best way to implement this with all scenarios
?

Comment: Do you use some ORM like Entity Framework or ADO.NET Commands?

Comment: I am using ado.net entity model

Comment: is there any good way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want exact match or contains?

Comment: I want exact match.. Contains not required

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is do an `empty check` or `like` for each input then `and` them all together in your where cause.

```
WHERE
    (RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(@FIELD1,''))) = '' OR [Column1] LIKE '%' + @FIELD1 +'%')
    AND (RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(@FIELD2,''))) = '' OR [Column2] LIKE '%' + @FIELD2 +'%')
```

... Since you are using ADO.Net make sure to use SqlParameters to prevent SQL injections.